# How to check the condition if checkbox is clicked or not using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My checkBoxes are dynamic and I only need to check condition if my checkbox with "OTHERS" are clicked or not.So My checkboxes are:

```
<div class="form-group" id="documents">
   <label> <input id="check_id1" type="checkbox" value="1" class="chk1" checked=""> <span>Invoice</span>
   <br>
   </label>
   <div style="padding-bottom: 5px"></div>
   <label> <input id="check_id2" type="checkbox" value="2" class="chk2" checked=""> <span>Packing List</span>
   <br>
   </label>
   <div style="padding-bottom: 5px"></div>
   <label> <input id="check_id3" type="checkbox" value="3" class="chk3" checked=""> <span>OTHERS</span>
   <br>
   </label>
   <div style="padding-bottom: 5px"></div>
</div>
```

So i tried to check if the **"Others"** checkboxes is checked or not but **alert()** is not triggered.

```
if($("span:contains('OTHERS')").prop('checked') == true){
                alert("here");

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not checking prop if input elm instead you are checking prop of span use this code

```
//gets the input
const elm = $("span:contains('OTHERS')").siblings()[0];
if($(elm).prop('checked')) alert("here");
```

Comment: is there a way i can put value="3" of OTHERS in a vairable if is is checked?

Comment: use `$(elm).prop('value');` to access value of input. Then you can set it to a variable under the condition when alert('here') is present

Answer (score 1):

It seems, we need to first check if Checkbox is checked or not, and then check if its siblings text value is equal to 'OTHERS'.

I have triggered the alert in this way:

```
  $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
   if($(this).prop('checked') == true && $(this).siblings("span").text() == "OTHERS"){
        alert("here");
    }
  });
```

We can also change HTML to simplify it further by directly assigning `value="OTHERS"` to checkbox.

```
$("input[value='OTHERS']").change(function(){
     if($(this).prop('checked') == true){
            alert("here");
        }
  });
```

Comment: is there a way i can put value="3" of OTHERS in a vairable if is is checked?

Comment: Yes, you can try  the code like this : $("input[value='3']")

Answer (score 0):

This is a DOM traversal issue - you need to go from the span UP to the parent and then DOWN to find the input- that is checked.

Also - note that putting checked="" in the input is the equivalent of checked="checked" - which is why this is showing as checked in the snippet.

EDIT - solution updated to allow the variable to be set based on the click of the label of "OTHERS"

```js
let myvariable;

$('label').click(function(){
  let spanText = $(this).find('span').text();
  let inputChecked = $(this).find('input').is(':checked')

  if(spanText == 'OTHERS' && inputChecked){
     myvariable = 3;
     alert(myvariable);
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" id="documents">
   <label> <input id="check_id1" type="checkbox" value="1" class="chk1"> <span>Invoice</span>
   <br>
   </label>
   <div style="padding-bottom: 5px"></div>
   <label> <input id="check_id2" type="checkbox" value="2" class="chk2"> <span>Packing List</span>
   <br>
   </label>
   <div style="padding-bottom: 5px"></div>
   <label> <input id="check_id3" type="checkbox" value="3" class="chk3"> <span>OTHERS</span>
   <br>
   </label>
   <div style="padding-bottom: 5px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a way i can put value="3" of OTHERS in a vairable if is is checked?

Comment: I just amended my solution to allow the value of 3 to be sotred in a variable if Others is checked.

Answer (score 0):

This will look across all checkboxes and check the one that has 'OTHERS'.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('#check').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(chk => {
      if(chk.parentNode.querySelector('span').innerText == 'OTHERS') {
        alert(chk.checked);
      }
    });
  });


});
```

```html
<div class="form-group" id="documents">
   <label> <input id="check_id1" type="checkbox" value="1" class="chk1" checked=""> <span>Invoice</span>
   <br>
   </label>
   <div style="padding-bottom: 5px"></div>
   <label> <input id="check_id2" type="checkbox" value="2" class="chk2" checked=""> <span>Packing List</span>
   <br>
   </label>
   <div style="padding-bottom: 5px"></div>
   <label> <input id="check_id3" type="checkbox" value="3" class="chk3" checked=""> <span>OTHERS</span>
   <br>
   </label>
   <div style="padding-bottom: 5px"></div>
</div>
<!-- Just for the answer -->
<button id="check">Check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const elm = $("span:contains('OTHERS')").closest("label").find("input[type=checkbox]");
if($(elm).prop('checked')) alert("here");
```